# JTextArea background issue

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

```
private JDialog dialog;
private JTextArea text;
private JPanel buttons, filler;
private JRadioButton questions, list;
private ButtonGroup group;
private JButton confirm;

dialog = new JDialog(Main.masterWindow, lang.getString("newTitle"), true);
dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(dialog.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
dialog.setResizable(false);

text = new JTextArea();

//this works
text.setBackground(Color.RED);

//this both don't
text.setBackground((Color)UIManager.get("control");
text.setBackground(dialog.getContentPane().getBackground());

dialog.setVisible(true);
```

I am using Nimbus L&F, and "control" is the background color of my dialog. If I set any other color (red in this example) it shows, but if I set it to this one, it's stays white.

I don't have tis problem on default (metal) L&F...

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it doesn't seem to like the `ColorUIResource` object the is returned from `UIManager.get` call.  I can't see why, because it's derived from `Color`.

If you do something like

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Help", true);
dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(dialog.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10, 10);

Color color = new Color(UIManager.getColor("control").getRGB()); // <-- Create a new color

text.setBackground(bg);

dialog.add(text);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

This seems to work.

Should you have to do it.  I don't think so, but every thing else I tried didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following code:

```
    System.out.println((Color)UIManager.get("control"));
```

This will print out what color exactly you are getting from the UIManager. Perhaps it is actually supposed to be white. Tell me what that prints

EDIT:

```
//this both don't
//text.setBackground(dialog.getContentPane.getBackground());
```

Well first off, you don't have () after getContentPane even though it is a method. Try doing it like this: `text.setBackground(dialog.getContentPane().getBackground());`

Comment: `javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=214,g=217,b=223]`

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it with creating new color with those RGB valuse, but I don't understand why can't I fetch color from dialog background?
In this case it's okay, but my dialogs background my be different, and I want the JTextArea to keep up, if I won't be able to access the color directly.

Comment: Nah, I just made a mistake here, it would return compiling error if I did it in Eclipse...

Comment: @Alex Coleman  [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#menubar)  and  [How To](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12382370/714968)