# how to remove JPopupMenu border in Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

I can remove the JPopupMenu border with `UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`
But it doesn't work with Nimbus. By looking at the [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) properties, I cannot find an entry to set the JPopupMenu border.

Is there a way to remove the border or to set the border color?

Comment: [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11759356/714968)